# R filter data that appear more than once but do not contain certain string

Tags: r, filter

I have a data frame as below. I want to first group the data frame by ID and Region, then  filter the data frame by Content. I want to keep ID-Region pair that only have both 'High' and 'Mid' in the Content column.

My current data frame:

```
structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d"), Content = c("High", "Mid", "Low", 
"High", "Mid", "High", "Mid", "High", "Mid", "High", "Mid", "High", 
"Mid", "Low"), Count = c("3", "6", "2", "3", "7", "3", "5", "8", 
"5", "4", "2", "4", "9", "5"), Region = c("East", "East", "East", 
"West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "East", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

My expect data frame:

```
structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"), 
    Content = c("High", "Mid", "High", "Mid", "High", "Mid", 
    "High", "Mid"), Count = c("3", "7", "3", "5", "8", "5", "4", 
    "2"), Region = c("West", "West", "East", "East", "East", 
    "East", "West", "West")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I try the following code, but I cannot keep ID-Region pair that only have both 'High' and 'Mid'.

```
newdata = data %>%
    group_by(ID,Region) %>%
    filter(n() != 1 & any(Content == "High") & any(Content == "Mid") & any(Content != "Low") %>%
    ungroup
```

Comment: I guess you need `filter(n() != 1 & any(c("High", "Mid") %in% Content) & Content %in% c("High", "Mid"))`

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the data instead of images

Comment: Hi @akrun, I use dput to show the data now. Thanks for your previous comment but it did not work.

Comment: Try the update in my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can filter to keep any groups that do not contain any `Content == Low` and that must contain `High` and `Mid`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID,Region) %>%
  filter(!any(Content == "Low") & all(c("High", "Mid") %in% Content) )
```

**Output**

```
  ID    Content Count Region
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> 
1 a     High    3     West  
2 a     Mid     7     West  
3 b     High    3     East  
4 b     Mid     5     East  
5 c     High    8     East  
6 c     Mid     5     East  
7 c     High    4     West  
8 c     Mid     2     West
```

Answer (score 2):

We can change the `filter` that shows only 'High', 'Mid' values by wrapping with `all`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(ID,Region) %>%    
   filter(all(c("High", "Mid") %in% Content), 
          all(Content %in% c("High", "Mid"))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  ID    Content Count Region
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> 
1 a     High    3     West  
2 a     Mid     7     West  
3 b     High    3     East  
4 b     Mid     5     East  
5 c     High    8     East  
6 c     Mid     5     East  
7 c     High    4     West  
8 c     Mid     2     West
```

---

Or use `n_distinct`

```
data %>%
   group_by(ID, Region) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(Content) == 2, 
          all(c("High", "Mid")  %in% Content)) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  ID    Content Count Region
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> 
1 a     High    3     West  
2 a     Mid     7     West  
3 b     High    3     East  
4 b     Mid     5     East  
5 c     High    8     East  
6 c     Mid     5     East  
7 c     High    4     West  
8 c     Mid     2     West
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update** to consider and implement suggestion by @AndrewGB's comment(1 and 2):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Region) %>%
    mutate(helper = ifelse(all(Content == "Mid") | 
                           all(Content == "High") | 
                           Content == "Low", "1", NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(helper, .direction = "up") %>% 
  filter(is.na(helper)) %>% 
  select(-helper)
```

**First answer:**
Do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Region) %>%
  filter(!any(Content == "Low"))
```

```
  ID    Content Count Region
  <chr> <chr>   <int> <chr> 
1 a     High        3 West  
2 a     Mid         7 West  
3 b     High        3 East  
4 b     Mid         5 East  
5 C     High        8 East  
6 C     Mid         5 East  
7 C     High        4 West  
8 C     Mid         2 West
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did first, but this would still return a group that only has "High" or "mid". But I think the OP wants it to be for groups with High and Mid (must contain both).

Comment: Good point. Please see my update. It is a little clunky but it should work.

Comment: I think that would still return if a group only had `High` in a group; at least using this slightly altered version of df: `structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "d", "d", "d"), Content = c("High", "Mid", "Low", "High", 
"High", "Mid", "High", "Mid", "High", "Mid", "High", "Mid", "Low"
), Count = c("3", "6", "2", "3", "3", "5", "8", "5", "4", "2", 
"4", "9", "5"), Region = c("East", "East", "East", "West", "East", 
"East", "East", "East", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))`

Comment: But I think this version of the `helper` would work: `mutate(helper = ifelse(all(Content == "Mid") | all(Content == "High") | Content == "Low", "1", NA_character_))`

Comment: Thanks for taking time and energy. I pasted your code to my answer!